# Qual è il senso di "pari" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> «Il verso va sentito in ogni suo accento», gorgogliava il maestoso Charles, seminudo sotto un immenso accappatoio rosso: «ogni sillaba **pari** il suo accento, Shakespeare deve essere ballabile, come Mozart, Dante e tutta la vera poesia».

Questo Charles che appare nel brano è Charles Laughton. No capisco il significato di "pari" in questo passaggio. 
Immagino sia il verbo "parare". Malgrado aver letto tutte le accezioni di questo verbo nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parare/) non riesco a vedere qual è il suo senso in questa frase. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Ogni sillaba "*all'altezza del*" suo accento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sta dicendo che bisogna accentare in particolar modo le sillabe di posto pari (la seconda, la quarta etc.): «ogni sillaba [in posizione] pari [abbia] il suo accento». Ciò combacia col fatto che a parlare sia un inglese, lingua in cui il verso drammatico scespiriano per eccellenza è il pentametro giambico che – semplificando – è composto da dieci sillabe di cui sono accentate appunto quelle in posizione pari:

> Arise, fair sun, and kill the envious moon,
>   Who is already sick and pale with grief

(Shakespeare, *Romeo and Juliet*).